# Installing a ipykernel and running jupyter notebook inside a virtual env - not using conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, virtualenv

I've hit a dead end trying to solve/debug this issue which doesn't seem like it should be that difficult.

I'm working in Pycharm IDE (not the professional) and I'm working inside a virtual environment let's call it `pythonProject` and I want to be able to run launch a jupyter notebook in this environment so that it can pick up all the python packages i've installed and configured for this environment.

As I understand it from the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html), these are the steps I need to take.

My terminal prompt statement:

`(pythonProject) oliver@oliver-u20:~/pythonProject$`

commands:

```sh
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m pip install notebook
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name pythonProject --display-name "Python (pythonProject)"
jupyter notebook
```

But when I load jupyter notebook, it only shows `python3` under kernels.

I tried outputting
`jupyter kernelspec list`
And get only the base kernel which suggests from [this](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html) that it's not finding my kernelspec, but I can't seem to figure from the [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html) what i'm supposed to do.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I've solved this.

I think there was an install issue with jupyter.

I tried reproducing this in a completely new project and venv and *could* get the kernel showing.

In the project and venv where I still couldn't, I noticed a discrepancy in the output of my `jupyter --paths`

In the working venv I could see under `data`
`/home/oliver/.local/share/jupyter`
Which is where the kernels I installed are located.

However in the project that wasn't working there was instead:
`/home/oliver/snap/jupyter/6/.local/share/jupyter`

I'm guessing this snap path is from how I originally installed jupyter on my Ubuntu via the app store - seemed sensible at the time.

So I uninstalled jupyter, restarted my venv and the `jupyter --paths` has magically changed so that
`/home/oliver/.local/share/jupyter`
is present and when I start a jupyter notebook at the command line with
`jupyter notebook`
I can see all my kernels showing!

I found this quite difficult to debug with the documentation and command help outputs so hope someone else finds this useful.